# Decomposing Number Addition in C

Tags: c, decomposition

I like to create a program that will decompose a number, suppose n = 123 expected out is

```
100 + 20 + 3
```

If the n = 103, expected output should be only

```
100 + 3
```

Is there any way easily to do this? Not having many if else statement? I've tried searching the net but I can't find my desired output in C language.

I hope this can be done in any digit number <100,000,000,000 if possible, Thank you!

This is what I tried so far...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  int n;
  int mod=0;
  int ten=0;
  int hun=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  
  
  if(n<10){
    printf("%d ",n);
  }
  else if(n<100){   
    ten = 10*(n/10);    
    mod = n - ten ;     
    printf("%d + %d",ten,mod);      
  }
  else if(n<1000){
    hun = 100*(n/100);      
    mod = n - hun ; 
    ten = 10*(mod/10);
    mod = n % (hun+ten) ;   
    printf("%d + %d + %d",hun,ten,mod);     
  } 


}
```

Comment: You seem to have under-specified the problem: how many terms do you want to decompose `n` into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done recursively, starting with the max power of ten 10,000,000,000 ; and in each recursive call you process the next lesser power of ten by dividing the previous max by 10, until it reaches 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void decompose(int n, long long ten_power, char *separator) {
    if (ten_power == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (n >= ten_power) {
        printf("%s%lld", separator, (n / ten_power) * ten_power);
        separator = " + ";
    }
    decompose(n % ten_power, ten_power / 10, separator);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    decompose(n, 100000000000LL, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best Approach! Thank you, I hope all are math wiz =D

Comment: I think that beyond personal satisfaction, my answer is more understandable than this piece of code, I doubt the op has understood it in fact, but has chosen the fancier stuff over simplicity and clarity. The only good reason to upvote this is that it doesn't require math library and is prone to case study, but in the end this definitely should not be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion. For large integers change `int` to `long / long long` based off of your requirements.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void func(int n) {

    // base condition
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }

    int k = 0, first = 0, val = n;

    // for every number get the no of digits to calculate the first part of the number (ex : 123 => no of digits = 3 and first part = 100)
    while (n) {
        if (n < 10) {
            first = n;
            break;
        }
        n = n/10;
        k++;
   }
  
  // printing
  k = (int)(first * (pow(10,k)));
  printf("%d", k);

  if (val - k) {
    printf(" + ");

    // recursing for the remaining part
    func(val - k);
  }

}

int main(){
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  func(n);
}
```

**Note:**
don't forget to link `-lm` while compiling the code (as you are using `math.h`)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to count the number of digits. After you know the number of digits you can find the power of each digit. Then you have to modulo your number with its highest power in every iteration in order to dump the highest digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    long n = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    long cpy = n;
    // Count numbers of digits
    while (cpy) {
        cpy /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    printf("Digits = %d\n", digits);
    while (digits) {
        long power = pow(10, digits - 1);
        long comp = n / power;
        n = n % power;
        printf("%lu\n", comp * power);
        digits--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You have to compile with the following in order to link the math.h library:

```
gcc <name of your C file> -lm
```

Note: I used long as a type because I did't know how big numbers you consider, you can even make it `long long` if you would like to make it work with higher numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    char n[10];
    scanf("%s", n);
    int out[10];
      
    for(int a=0; a<strlen(n); ++a) {
        char c = n[a];//one character at a time to be used with atoi()
        out[a] = atoi(&c) * (int) pow(10.0f, (double) strlen(n)-a-1);
        printf("%d ", out[a]);
    }
}
```

There needs to be a loop on the length of the word, you retrieve each character one by one and use `atoi` (ascii to integer) then the `pow()` method from math.h with the exponant at `strlen(n)-a-1` to get the correct number.